# Standing for Grace after Meals to concentrate better?

Tags: bentching, standing-sitting

I have seen someone choose to learn standing up rather than sitting because he was tired. He felt he could stay awake better in a standing position.

When it comes to Grace after Meals, the [SO O.Ch. 183 (9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.183.9?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en) rules that it should be done sitting “in order to have more concentration”. The Rema says that one will have fulfilled the mitzva even if he was not sitting.

My question is therefore if someone thinks that he can have more concentration in  Grace after Meals if he recites it standing should he rather stand than sit?

Comment: Good question, I think, but initial thoughts: it says צריך לישב. The two cases are also not comparable in anything beyond they both should be done with concentration

Comment: Standing to learn is always the ideal posture (Megillah 21a). The special leniency is to learn seated if it improves your concentration.

Answer (score 0):

The Rema says there

> מיהו אם לא עשו כן אפי' בירך מהלך בדיעבד יצא
>
> However if he did not do so (i.e. sit) even if he walks around, he has
> 'bdiavad' done his duty.

I asked my Rav. He said that the word 'bdiavad' includes both the case of someone who **happened** to say Grace after Meals standing and the case of someone who **deliberately** stood for a specific reason like mine.

So it is worth standing if it may result in more concentration.

Comment: Doing something deliberately bedieved may still count, but the very meaning of the word "bedieved" is "not the ideal way" so I don't think that your conclusion is justified by the logic

Comment: @RabbiKaii isn't bediavad = in that he did it = ex post facto = after the fact, no more and no less?

Comment: @NissimNanach https://dinonline.org/2012/03/29/meaning-of-bedieved/

Comment: @rabbikaii Not the ideal way is not the ideal way to translate bediavad, even bediavad. It's ex post facto period and I'll post the Jastrow..

Comment: ‎דיעבד‎ ‎m. ‎(=דאיעבד, ‎Dithpe. ‎of ‎עבד) ‎having ‎been ‎done, ‎diaibad, ‎a ‎dialectical ‎term ‎to ‎indicate ‎that ‎the ‎case ‎before ‎you ‎is ‎dealt ‎with ‎as ‎a ‎fact, ‎and ‎not ‎with ‎reference ‎to ‎its ‎direct ‎permissibility ‎in ‎the ‎premises, ‎לכתחילה; ‎as ‎a fact, ‎decision ‎ex ‎post ‎facto. ‎Hull. ‎2a ‎לכתחילה ‎שוחטין ‎הכל ‎ד׳ ‎כשרה ‎ושחיטתן ‎the ‎words ‎of ‎the ‎Mishnah ‎(I, ‎1), ‎...

Comment: @NissimNanach in the same way "jew" means "descendant of Yehuda"? Words have _exact_ meanings, but the primary way we understand terms is their _practical_ meanings (common meaning). Bedieved commonly, practically means something in halacha, beyond it's _exact_ meaning i.e. as it says in the link I provided = not the ideal way, but still valid. I hear though, I will ask the moderator to change my wording

Comment: @rabbikaii Yes and tanks.